# topological type of smooth manifolds with prescribed homotopy type and pontryagin class

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, surgery-theory, characteristic-classes

Can someone help explain the following result:

If the dimension is at least five, there are at most finitely many different smooth manifolds with given homotopy type and Pontryagin classes.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Diffeomorphism classes of smooth manifolds... but I guess people would know what you meant. How much detail do you need?

Answer (score 11):

In the $1$-connected case, one may argue as follows:

Let $X$ be a closed $1$-connected smooth $n$-manifold, $n \ge 5$. The theory of the Spivak fibration shows that any homotopy equivalence  $f: M^n \to X$ with $M$ smooth
is covered by a stable fiber homotopy equivalence of underlying stable tangent spherical fibrations  of $M$ and $X$.  Call $f$  *stably tangential*  if this
equivalence of stable spherical fibrations lifts to an isomorphism of stable tangent vector bundles.

Then the surgery exact sequence
shows that any stable tangential homotopy equivalence $f: M \to X$ 
is homotopic to a diffeomorphism $f': M \sharp \Sigma \to X$, where $\Sigma$ is a homotopy sphere, and $\sharp$ means connected sum.

(You can either quote here Corollary II.3.8 of Browder's book, or you can deduce it directly from the surgery exact sequence. The point is that connected sum gives an action of the homotopy $n$-spheres on the the structure set of $X$, and one can compare the surgery exact sequence for $M$ and the sphere to deduce the above statement.)

To finish the proof of what you want, notice:

1. Kervaire and Milnor showed that there are only finitely many homotopy spheres in each dimension $\ge 5$.
2. The obstruction to the homotopy equivalence being stably tangential is given by its normal invariant, which is an element of $[X,\text{G/O}]$ (it's given by the "difference" between the stable tangent bundles of $M$ and $X$, i.e., $(f^{-1})^*\tau_M - \tau_X$, appropriately interpreted).
3. The map $\text{G/O} \to B\text{O}$ is a rational homotopy equivalence (by Serre). The image of the normal invariant in $[X,B\text{O}]$ is rationally detected by the difference of the Pontryagin classes of $M$ and $X$ using the fact that $H^*(B\text{O}; \Bbb Q)$ is a polynomial algebra on the $p_i$.

Comment: I should also mention that $G$ is the topological monoid whose classifying space classifies stable spherical fibrations. Its homotopy groups coincide with the homotopy groups of spheres in positive degrees. So it has trivial rational homotopy.

Comment: Without assuming $1$-connectedness I doubt that the statement is true. Can't there be infinitely many manifolds all h-cobordant but not diffeomorphic?

Comment: Yes, I suspected as much...

Comment: @Goodwillie: Is there a reference for that fact?
@Klein: great answer!

Comment: @John: Could you give some details of the 3rd point,i.e. why the normal invariant is rationally detected by the difference of L class of domain and range?

Comment: @sara: there's a fiber sequence $G/O \to BO \to BG$ and $BG$ is rationally contractible (since its homotopy groups in positive degreesare the stable homotopy groups of spheres shifted by one). The map $X\to G/O \to BO$ is given by the difference of tangent bundles, as in second point.  On the other hand the map from $BO$ to the product of rational Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces $K(Q,4k)$ (given by the product of the Pontryagin classes $BO \to K(Q,4k)$ is a rational homotopy equivalence by the calculation of the rational cohomology of $BO$.

Comment: @ John say $H^\ast (K(Q,4i))\cong Q[k_{4i}]$,then the classifying map $c\in [X,G/O]$ corresponding to $\tau_M-(f^{-1})^*\tau_X$ is mapped to $c^*(1+k_4+\cdots+k_{4i})\in H^*(X,Q)$ under the identification $[X,G/O]\otimes Q\cong \oplus H^{4i}(X,Q)$. My question is: How to see that the $L$ class in $H^*(BO)$ is mapped to the $L$ class for $\tau_M-(f^{-1})^*\tau_X$  by $(j\circ c)^\ast$ where $j:G/O\to BO$

Comment: @sara Isn't that just naturality?

Comment: @ John  Thanks ! i did not understand correctly one argument in my book, which caused this confusion.